# Compare objects in an array

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have an array of objects.

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, objN]
```

every objects has 3 properties key, name, description.

How can i compare these objects for equality, two objects are equal if they have the same key.

But if a have lets say 4 objects they all must have the same key to be equal.

Comment: i thought taking the first object and comparing with the other objects but it doesnt feel right.

Comment: Seems like you have a good grasp of the concept, so what's the issue? Just write the code for the process you've outlined...

Comment: Comparing all objects to the first object is the way to go, actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. <sub>[(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)</sub>

Example:

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, objN];
var allTheSame = array.every(function(element){
    return element.key === array[0].key;
});
```

Please note that [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is IE 9+. However, there's a nice [polyfill on the mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) for older versions of IE.

If you really want to use a for loop, you could do it like this:

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, objN];
var allTheSame = array.length == 1;

for(var i = 1; i < array.length && (array.length > 1 && allTheSame); i++){
    allTheSame = array[0].key == array[i].key;
}
```

Try it for:

```
[{key:1},{key:1},{key:1}]; // true
[{key:1},{key:1},{key:2}]; // false
[{key:1},{key:2},{key:1}]; // false
[{key:1}]; // true
```

Comment: _"But if a have lets say 4 objects they all must have the same key to be equal."_ I think the question is pretty clear, @Zeshan.

Answer (score -3):

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, objN];
for(i = 0, i < array.length; i++){
    for(j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
        if(array[i].key == array[j].key){
            // Your logic whatever you want to do here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you nesting `for` loops? o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus So that i can compare selecting index with rest of objects in array. In this way i dont have to go back to first index every time  i go to next index. It works. Copy code and check in you console. you just have to pass actual objects in array

Comment: That's a lot of redundant checking. If you compare the first object to _all_ other objects in the array, and they're all the same as the first, why would you need to do the same check for the 2nd object again?

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm avoiding issue you mentioned by second for loop so that i dont have to compare twice. Just give it a dry run.

Comment: There is no issue. If _all_ elements in the array have to be the same, you _only_ need to iterate over the array _once_, to compare all objects to the first one.

Comment: @Cerbrus Outer loop is selecting object to compare and inner loop will iterate over remaining array. In second loop I'm initializing j = j + 1. In this way it will not compare to itself.

Comment: You __don't need to__ "select" anything. You just need to compare all elements to the first one. I'll write up a `for` loop in my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think i took the wrong case if you need to check only if all the objects in array are same then you are right.  but what if we want to get all unique elements. I think misunderstood the requirements.