# How can I compare values between objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been scratching my head for a long time with this one, even tough it feels like an easy task. I have an array with a set of objects. The array looks like this:

```
[ { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: '--', key3: 'ok' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' } ]
```

I want a function that compares the objects, and returns the key that has all "ok" as it's value. In this case, I'd like it to return

```
key1
```

I've been watching [Compare objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399121/compare-objects-in-an-array) for inspiration, but it just doesn't do it.

Do anyone have any suggestions? Would be a life saver

Comment: If you can use ES6: `arr.reduce((s, o) => (Object.keys(o).filter(k => o[k] !== 'ok').forEach(k => s.delete(k)), s), new Set(Object.keys(arr[0])));` https://jsfiddle.net/qemuyf3f/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the array and filter the keys.

```js
var array = [{ key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' }, { key1: 'ok', key2: '--', key3: 'ok' }, { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        return r.filter(function (k) {
            return o[k] === 'ok';
        });    
    }, Object.keys(array[0]));

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [{ key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' }, { key1: 'ok', key2: '--', key3: 'ok' }, { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => r.filter(k => o[k] === 'ok'), Object.keys(array[0]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting approach @Nina!  Would not have thought of starting with the full list and filtering out as you iterate...

Comment: @rasmeister, it is not necessary the full list, but anyway it performs an and operation over at least the key which are common and have the wanted value.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not the shortest solution, but should be easy to follow..

```js
var obj = [ { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: '--', key3: 'ok' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' } ];

var keycount = {};

obj.forEach((o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach((key) => {
    if (o[key] === 'ok') 
      keycount[key] = (keycount[key] || 0) + 1;
  });
});
Object.keys(keycount).forEach((key) => {
  if (keycount[key] === obj.length) 
    console.log(`Found ${key}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all objects have identical keys:

```
  for (var key in arr[0]){
     var allok = true;
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i][key] !== "ok") {
           allok = false;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (allok) {console.log(key);}
  }
```

Comment: Same here,.  Try making into a working snippet.. It's actually easier than using a code block, just press the `<>` button..

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```js
var objs = [ { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: '--', key3: 'ok' },
  { key1: 'ok', key2: 'ok', key3: '--' } ];

var getOkKeys = function(objs) {
  return Object.keys(objs[0]).reduce(function(results, key) {
    if (objs.every(function(obj) { return (obj[key] === 'ok'); })) {
      results.push(key);
    }
    return results;
  }, []);
};

console.log(getOkKeys(objs));
```

As requested, a function that returns the keys - `getOkKeys()`.

Comment: Nice solution,.. To make things a little nicer,  in the future try making into a working snippet..  It's the `<>` symbol..  I've done it here for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Good advice